# Beam deflection using trapezoidal rule in matlab?

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to plot the deflection equation for a simply supported beam using the trapezoidal method. I have two equations that describe the deflection of the beam. Each equation is vaild over a different range of x along the beam. I would like to know how to plot the curve for the whole beam, for the entire range of x. I don't know how to tell matlab that each equation is only valid for a specific range of x and that both equations together describe the deflection of the beam.

Can any one offer any help or suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: I think you'll need to be more specific to get help. Are you looking for something like
`x = -1:.01:1;`
`inside = abs(x)<.5;`
`y(inside) = sin(x(inside));`
`y(~inside) = cos(x(~inside));`
`plot(x, y)`

Comment: You could set up `y1` and `y2`, which are the deflections calculated by both equations, and then make `y_real` by combining samples from the first two. `y_real = [y1(1:44) y2(45:103)]` or similar